# AddIn - get AppDomain from currently debugging process

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio-2008, add-in

is it possible to get the current appdomain from a debugging process in an addin?
currently i use the DebuggerEvents.OnEnterBreakMode-Event to get in the right place.
i need access to HttpContext.Current of the debugged application.

greetz
mo

Answer (score 0):

A little late maybe, but you can use `AddInController.GetAddInController(addIn).AppDomain` to get the appdomain.